combinatorics question with restriction
I have the following question:

From a team of professionals with four engineers and five technicians, the aim is to form a group of five professionals with at least one engineer and one technician. Under these conditions, how many different possibilities are there for forming this group of five professionals?

I've solved it using the approach of getting all possible teams of five professionals (regardless of being engineer or technician) and then subtrating it by the situations when the pre-requisite wasn't met (at least one of each position):
$${9\choose 5} - 1 = 125$$
In this cenario, finding the case where the situation wasn't met was easy, bacause it was only one possibility (all team composed by technicians). But how can I solve it when it isn't so simple to find those situations?
I've tried to get to the same result through the following thinking proccess:

calculate possible "teams" of 1 engineers
calculate possible "teams" of 1 technician
calculate the rest of the team with the remaing 7 persons
multiply the results from items 1, 2 and 3

$${4\choose 1}{5\choose 1}{7\choose 3} = 700$$
Why the result is different?
Is there a way to solve the problem without having to know the situations where the pre-requisite isn't met?

Your second method multicounts.  For example, if Engineer Eddy is in your team of $1$ engineer and Engineer Ethel is on your team in the remaining $7$ persons, you're also counting that same combination by placing Ethel on the team of $1$ and Eddy in the remaining $7$.  The general method of solving these problems is the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

Here's a direct approach:
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{4} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{3} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{5}{2} + \binom{4}{4}\binom{5}{1} = 4 \cdot 5 + 6 \cdot 10 + 4 \cdot 10 + 1 \cdot 5 = 125$$
